# get uid from pid(process id) from kernel level code

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I would like to get uid of a pid. Please note that the uid that I want to get is NOT of the current process.
Please let me know if you have an idea.
Maybe can I get it by reuse the function of /proc/[pid]/status read function in kernel?
//Bruce

Answer (score 2):

1. Search process descriptor (`struct task_struct`) with given pid.
2. Use `task->cred->uid`.

Struct `struct task_struct` is defined in `include/linux/sched.h`. Struct `struct cred` is defined in `include/linux/cred.h`.

Note, that iterating through processes and reading process's credentials should be done under RCU-critical section.

Comment: doesn't `gid` refers to `group id` ?

Comment: Looks like it was misprint. Now it is fixed. Thanks for pointing out.